# How to perform OCR on a Excel sheets/table form with Tesseract?

Tags: excel, ocr, tesseract

I'm trying to develop an mobile application for OCR recognition of table form or Excel file, then extract the data into a Excel file. I've seen some online tools for doing that and I'm wondering if Tesseract can do it too?

Comment: You want to ocr an excel file and put the results into an excel file ... ?

Comment: I want both of them, but the tricky part for me now is OCR an excel